# How to print all values in foreach

Tags: groovy

Groovy for-each returns only one value.which is first value please check it once.how to print all values

```
  def list = [1,2,3,4]
   for(item in list){
    return item
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean `println list` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def list = [1,2,3,4]
for(item in list){
  print item
}
```

`return` is completely different thing. it is used for a function/method to evaluate a value.

Comment: in file maker i'm trying to print the above with println but doesn't print anything

Comment: i don't know what you mean by file maker, but  here it is. execute it please.
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5195878092505088

Answer (score 0):

You `return` from the method during the very first iteration of the loop. The loop will never execute more than the first iteration for that reason.

Comment: thanks.for printing all in groovy format what should i do ?